# Given a list of integers, find the smallest integer that cannot be expressed as a combination of those numbers (with +, / and *)

Tags: python, math, combinatorics

*"Given a list of integers, find the smallest integer that cannot be expressed as a combination of those numbers, **in order**. (with +, / and *, we use / only if the result of the division is an integer)"*

Example:
Given 1, 2 and 3 i can express:

```
1 = (1 + 2) / 3  
2 Cannot be expressed  
3 Cannot be expressed  
4 Cannot be expressed  
5 = 1 * 2 + 3  
6 = 1 + 2 + 3  
7 Cannot be expressed (we cannot write "1 + (2*3)" because it's not in order.)
```

So 2 is the smallest number that cannot be expressed as a combination of 1, 2 and 3.

I tried to generate every combination possible to check the first number in range that cannot be expressed as a combination :

```py
def gen_ints(nbs, s=None):
    if s is None:     # If there's no sum (first time we enter in the func)
        s = nbs[0]    # Take the first number
        nbs = nbs[1:]

    if len(nbs) == 0:  # If there's no number left
        if s >= 0:
            return [s] # Return the sum
        return []

    a = nbs[0]         # If there's still some numbers, take the first nb
    l = []
    l += gen_ints(nbs[1:], s + a) # Recursively compute every combination with it
    l += gen_ints(nbs[1:], s * a)
    if s % a == 0:
        l += gen_ints(nbs[1:], s // a)
    return l # Final list of all combinations
```

But the complexity is way too high (I can't compute all the combinations of more than 15 numbers)

Comment: Try memoizing the recursive function, Time complexity should reduce to O(n^2)

Comment: Also first sort the array and then go one by one from small to big

Comment: This will make you basically perform something similar to 0-1 knapsack, even though 0-1 Knapsack will need to computed for each element of the array, you can share the dp table across the iterations....?

Comment: @AnuraagBarde What should be memorized ?

Answer (score 1):

For fun, here is a brute force solution:

*NB. if you want only the solution **in order** there is one block of code to comment*

##### gets first possibility

```
from itertools import product
from functools import reduce
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

ops = {'/': truediv, '×': mul, '+': add, '−': sub}

a,b,c = 1,2,3
for i in range(10):
    for op1, op2 in product(ops, repeat=2):
        f1 = ops[op1]
        f2 = ops[op2]
        if f2(f1(a,b),c) == i:
            print(f'{i:>3}: ({a}{op1}{b}){op2}{c}')
            break
        if f1(a,f2(b,c)) == i:                       # remove this block 
            print(f'{i:>3}: {a}{op1}({b}{op2}{c})')  # for only solutions
            break                                    # in order (a…b)…c
    else:
        print(f'{i:>3}: no result')
```

output:

```
  0: (1+2)−3
  1: (1+2)/3
  2: (1−2)+3
  3: no result
  4: no result
  5: (1×2)+3
  6: (1×2)×3
  7: 1+(2×3)
  8: no result
  9: (1+2)×3
```

##### gets all possibilities

```
from itertools import product
from functools import reduce
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

ops = {'/': truediv, '×': mul, '+': add, '−': sub}

a,b,c = 1,2,3
for i in range(10):
    print(f'{i:>3}: ', end='')
    sep = ''
    for op1, op2 in product(ops, repeat=2):
        f1 = ops[op1]
        f2 = ops[op2]
        if f2(f1(a,b),c) == i:
            print(f'{sep}({a}{op1}{b}){op2}{c}', end='')
            sep = ', '
        if f1(a,f2(b,c)) == i:
            print(f'{sep}{a}{op1}({b}{op2}{c})', end='')
            sep = ', '
    print()
```

output:

```
  0: (1+2)−3, 1+(2−3)
  1: (1+2)/3
  2: (1−2)+3, 1−(2−3)
  3: 
  4: 
  5: (1×2)+3, 1×(2+3)
  6: (1×2)×3, 1×(2×3), (1+2)+3, 1+(2+3)
  7: 1+(2×3)
  8: 
  9: (1+2)×3
```